# Use variable to access multiple objects

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I would like to be able to access objects in a for-loop as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<5: i++)
{ object[i].doSomething(); }
```

However the syntax around the `object[i]` part escapes me.

Comment: http://www.oopweb.com/Java/Documents/ThinkCSJav/Volume/chap11.htm

Comment: Binyamin's answer is a good one. However, you should know that this code won't work at all if `object` is indeed and object. This syntax is used for accessing elements of an array in a C-like syntax (Java, C++, Javascript, etc). If `object` is an ArrayList, then you'll want to do `object.get(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (        // loop
int i = 0;   // initialize the variable i before starting to iterate
i < 5;       // perform the block below while i < 5
i ++ )       // increment i after performing the block below
{                      // start of block to execute in each iteration of the for-loop
    object[i]          // the i-th element of the array object
    .doSomthing();     // call this method on ^^ 
}                      // end block
```

Good references:

- [Java array tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Java control flow statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)